# MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, applicationcontext

I'm trying to run a java batch that call an application context without success (it's a java app that calls a Camel spring context). This is what I'm getting during the startup:

```
ERROR ApplicationProperties @ addApplicationProperty [28] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [/MessageRouting/src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/LOCALHOST-db-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
Fatal error! java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading ClassPathXmlApplicationContext file - src/test/resources/META-INF/spring/LOCALHOST-db-context.xml
```

I'm using spring 4.2.3 (updated yesterday, probably the reason for which it doesn't work. It was 4.0.9). I know that MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter has been replaced by MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter but, how can I tell to spring to use the new version???

I followed some suggestion and I added this to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

but it doesn't work. What make me really angry is that with previous version worked and even if I come back to the previous version it doesn't work now. Any clue?

I added also this, but without success:

```
 <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
     <property name="messageConverters">
         <list>
             <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
         </list>
     </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
 <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
```

[Btw, I fixed same issue last summer but I forgot how :(]

Comment: Show pom , what version spring mvc?

Comment: Version is 4.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed adding this dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using spring 4.0.3 for our project. I could see the class MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter in spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar.

Do you perhaps have any configuration related to MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter? Because, I am using the same configuration as follows and it is working for me.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
```

And our project also has jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar and jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar in our classpath.

Answer (score 0):

use this :-

```
<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring.controller" />
```

Replace `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`